# Can't n run a bootable cd of ubuntu desktop on a laptop with no OS

Tags: boot-failure

I recorded a bootable CD with the image that I downloaded from the Ubuntu site, using NTI CD MAKER.
My laptop had a problem and I prefered to get it fixed without installing an OS. Now, when I try to run this CD it shows the following error mssage:

```
 Device driver not found: 'MSCD001'.

 No valid CDROM device drivers were selected

 Mouse driver was previously installed

 A:\>
```

If the drive wasn't working the CD wouldn't even start, I assume....So can anyone help me please!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the CD you burned contains DOS rather than Ubuntu (or perhaps contains both). One possible cause of this is if you told your CD burning software to do something special to make the CD bootable. Ubuntu `.iso` images are already bootable, so you don't need to do anything like that.

I recommend making a new CD using one of the officially recommended techniques [described here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-windows). The problem here appears to be in the way you have used your CD burning software (or a bug in the software), and it would be difficult for us to give you advice about how specifically to correct that unless someone here happens to be experienced with the utility you used.

Alternatively, you might consider booting Ubuntu from a [USB flash drive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) rather than a CD.

If you continue to have trouble, you should make sure to [MD5 test](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) the Ubuntu `.iso` image you downloaded.

This answer assumes you are booting from the CD correctly. The term "try to run this CD" is a bit confusing, though, so if my answer doesn't help, can you clarify what exactly you are doing with the CD after you burn it?

Comment: I recorded an ISO file from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and then burned it to a CD...when I tried to run it on the laptop nothing happened....

Comment: The first CD i recorded it without giving the instruction to create a bootable cd, the 2nd one, I extracte the files to a folder and recorded then, adding the instructiuon that I wanted to create a bootable file...

Comment: is there a way I can do anything from the A:/> prompt line?

Comment: You can press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Del` to reboot your computer. Besides that, no, there's almost certainly no way for you to get into Ubuntu from that.

Comment: @csbl What do you mean by "tried to run it"? What did you do with it, exactly, after you burned it? Did you reboot your computer, press the key that brings up your BIOS boot menu, and select to boot off the CD? Or did you do something else? When you say "nothing happened", was that for the 1st CD, or something else? And what do you mean when you say "nothing happened"? What *did* happen? Did you have a completely blank screen? Did the computer boot normally as though there were no CD in the drive? Or something else?

Comment: I did now...but I leads to the same messages...

Comment: @csbl You did *what* now? Are you talking about the BIOS boot menu? Or are you saying that you followed [these instructions exactly](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-windows) and got the same messages and `A:\>` prompt?

Comment: When I say 'I tried to run it' it means I inserted it into the cd drive and hoped it would show something about ubuntu or a least any instructions

Comment: @csbl Have you tried creating a new CD by [following these instructions exactly](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-windows) yet? Or is a problem occurring that is preventing you from being able to do that?

Comment: Yes, I followed the instructions of NTI CD MAKER which are basically the same, and I even tested the recording firts, before recoding it for real, in order to check if there was anything wrong. When I insert the CD  with the ISO file it shows, on the black screen:

Comment: (sorry...It's the 'enter' problem that gets to make so many comments... :|)

In the black screen it shows, when i insert the cd with the iso file,: "No bootable device - insert boot disk and press any key"

Comment: @csbl Clearly neither CD was able to boot right. As it would be very difficult to support NTI CD MAKER here (I haven't used it and it's not very widely used), the reason for you to [follow these instructions exactly](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-windows) is for you to *use a utility that is known to work for this purpose*. The problem might not be with the way you are using NTI CD MAKER. It could be with NTI CD MAKER itself. But even if you are making a mistake, it's unlikely that I could identify it (unless maybe you can post a *video* showing everything you did with it).

Comment: "Right before that message there is one hat says:

PXE-E61:Media test failure, check cbale
PXE-MOF: Exiting PXE ROM"

All the messages that I refer to are no from BIOS, but from the 'usual' black screen.

Comment: @csbl Please **edit your question** to include *all* messages you see when you try to boot the CD, and please make clear how you created the CD that gave you these messages. In addition, please try using [one of the CD burning utilities in these instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-windows) or explain why you are not able to do so. You should add all this information to your question, as comments on AskUbuntu are subject to deletion/editing by moderators at any time, plus it's difficult for someone else (besides you and me) to understand what's going on.

Comment: I used the recorder it is available on this laptop, which is not my own, and I didn't think that that could be a proble, honnestly. This laptop is running windows and so the software I use is windows compliant. Is there a way we can exchange these comments somewhere else (mail or chat). This is because this post it's almost becoming one.

Comment: I am now going to try to do it with a pen drive...I'm running out of CDs...

Comment: @csbl I understand (and agree) with not installing other CD burning software on someone else's computer. Depending on what version of Windows it is running, you might be able to burn the `.iso` file from Windows Explorer, without installing any other software. In any case trying with a USB flash drive (pen drive) instead is probably a good idea, and depending on the cause of the problem, will likely just work. [I've created a chat room and I think I've set it up so you can join.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3658/discussion-between-csbl-and-eliah-kagan) If you can't, please let me know.

Comment: I opened the link but I guess I need something else, like reputation, to be able to chat.... I believe it has to be 20 of reputation...

Comment: I've downloaded the Universal USB  Installer. Which Linux distribution should I select? This will install for real an OS on my ther laptop, or will it run 'run on memory'?

Comment: I'll be back tomorrow...It's too late here!

Comment: @csbl [These instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) explain how to make an bootable Ubuntu live USB with the Universal USB Installer. Night!

Comment: I'm stuck on the Partition Part. I'm not used to dealing with other OS other than Windows and that is a problem. What should I do? I want 2 partitons. One where I can no install Ubuntu and later on Windows, and another one just to keep my files and folders etc. Can you give me some hints. I thought of primamry partitions with FAT32

Comment: @csbl I'm glad you were able to boot the USB flash drive and run the installer. Your question about partitions is totally different from your original question here, so you should create a new, separate question about this. Not only will that work best for getting you an answer, but then the answer will be prominently visible, and will benefit others.